# Solving scrolling element inside below div (under screen) - I want to have it fixed after scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, screen

I do not know how to solve this situation:

I`ve got the html/css looks like this:
Image showing how my css/html looks like and what is displayed on the screen after landing on page: [image]

The when I scroll down I see green element:
scrolling down -> [image]

After continuing to scrolling down I saw full green element and the if I scroll down I want to have this element like in css language: position fixed bottom 0. See image below:
I ve saw full element -> same link but image called problem3.png

and then I scroll below and I want to have it fixed at the bottom of the page, like on this image:

Fixed element on screen - What I want and I do not know how to do that -> same link but image called problem4.png (stupid spam prevention mechanism)

Is it possible to solve this situation ?

To sum up: I`ve got two divs, one above and second below, Wheen I scroll down I suddenly see another element (green div) and when i continue to scroll down I WANT TO HAVE THIS GREEN DIV FIXED AT THE BOTTOM OF THE PAGE.

Ofcourse, when I scroll up (back on the top) I want to "park" that green div at the top of the second div.

Is there any way to solve this situation with jQuery (Javascript) / html / css ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to show some of your html structure. There are lots of ways to achieve this kind of effect. Fundamentally, in javascript terms you'll be looking to:

1. Add an event listener to the window scroll that checks whether the green element is fully in view
2. If it is in view, add a class (or change it's css) that fixes it's position where you want
3. Change your window scroll method so that it's checking the relative offset of the red div to the top of the screen. If it goes below the position where the green div should be fixed, remove the class you added earlier.

That sounds complicated, but it's not too bad. The javascript would be something like:

```
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {

    if($(".divToFix").hasClass("fixedAtBase")){
        if(Utils.underView($(".redDiv"), $(".divToFix").height())) $(".divToFix").removeClass("fixedAtBase");
    } else {
        if(Utils.inView($(".divToFix"))) $(".divToFix").addClass("fixedAtBase");
    }

  });


});

Utils = {
    underView: function(element, offset) {
        return (($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() - offset) <= element.offset().top);
    },

    aboveView: function(element) {
        return ($(window).scrollTop() >= element.offset().top + element.height());
    },

    inView: function(element) {
        return (Utils.aboveView(element) !== true && Utils.underView(element, element.height()) !== true);
    }
};
```

Bear in mind I've not tested that or anything.

edit - here's a [demo](http://jsbin.com/oluxen/4/edit)